# Error trying to get disk space usage from discovered VMS using Zabbix

Tags: monitoring, esxi, zabbix, vcenter

I am trying to create a trigger on a template called Template Virt VMware Guest in order to extract the % of free space of the VMWARE VM that has the template inherited.

What I did was:

Going to the template and create the following item: And the I created a trigger for trigger it once the% of free space on each of the disks is less than 10x.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkPqy.png)

Here you have the way I configured it: But when I link it the template to some host I get the following error: What might be the problem? Am I doing something wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkPqy.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BG57V.png)